# How to develop and run spark scala from vscode using sbt or Metals

Tags: scala, apache-spark, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn Spark Scala. I am able to develop and run them in Eclipse. I wanted to use VSCode and after googling for a while I do not find any proper post which explain how to setup sbt file and run. I also came across new plugin called "Metals" for VSCode to build Spark Scala code but again there is no proper material available to implement. Request if some can help me or direct me to any post to achieve my goal.

Thanks
L

Answer (score 8):

First, you have to create a `build.sbt` file in your project folder with minimal contents like:

```
name := "Simple Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.0-preview2"
```

After saving the file, if you open this folder from VS Code, you should see this message:

[image]

Click *Import build* and you should be all set.

In case you have a problem (like a missing library), metals should log it to its *Output* window.

If the dialog does not pop-up, go to your console and manually issue `sbt package` to make sure your environment is correctly set up.

To run the code, simply press ^F5. It will create a default `launch.json` file where you can specify your build targets. Anything else like syntax highlighting, formatting, and code inspection will just work out of the box.

If you want to run your Spark code locally, just add `.config("spark.master", "local")` to your `SparkConfig`.

Comment: Quick note to the rushed reader: Install the Scala (Metals) Language Server extension.

Comment: How to make it by maven ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the master url hardcoded you could use the jvmOptions in the launch.json to pass the master url whem executing spark job with

```
"jvmOptions": ["-Dspark.master=local[*]"]
```